# CRM 2013 - Bulk Update User Setting for 'Current Format' (UK Date format..)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, settings

Does anyone know of a way of bulk updating Dynamics CRM 2013 Users to have the UK date format selected under the 'Current Format' User Setting? Either via code or using an existing tool.

I did have a tool that I used for CRM 2011 but this doesn't seem to be available any more. The XrmToolbox has a settings update tool but doesn't allow changing of this setting.

Alternatively does anyone know if their isn't a tool if this can be updated manually from the *UserSettings* table? (although I know this is unsupported)

Comment: If any down votes - please can you provide feedback so I can improve the question rather than just down voting..

Comment: This looks like a good question because according to site guidelines it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"  - Upvoted

Comment: Thanks Zach, hopefully someone has some pointers to help out :)

Comment: Are you actually able to set the date format for individual users in 2013?  All I am seeing is the date format under the "Formats" tab in Administration->System Settings.

Comment: Yes you can set it per User from settings

Answer (score 3):

I once wrote some code to do something similar.

To update the settings for an individual user, you should be able to do something like (although I haven't tried it):

```
Entity us = new Entity("usersettings");
us["systemuserid"] = Row.systemuserid;
us["localid"] = 2057;  //UK
CRMservice.Update(us);
```

List of localid's is available from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(WinEmbedded.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [xrmtoolbox](https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com). There is tool called "user settings utility" that should allow you to modify user settings in bulk.

I believe usersettings table update should work as well, but I'd assume tool above uses SDK, which is more supported way.

Comment: Hi Mario, This tool does not support changing this setting.

Comment: Shame :( I. wasn't aware of that. Mike's answer is good pointer, and there's always sql update as option :)